# Is there a term for a function that acts as an "instance method" in C?

Tags: c, terminology

There are no classes in C, but it is simple enough to create something similar by defining a struct that contains all the "class"'s properties, and representing its methods by functions that take pointers to said struct as their first arguments. I am in the process of documenting a header file of this form.

I'm trying to figure out how to refer to this sort of function without using object-oriented terminology like "method". I could just invent my own name for it and define it, but considering how common these sort of functions are, I assume there's already a standard way to refer to them. Am I correct? If so, how do I refer to them?

Comment: `Am I correct?` The standard terminology is a "method". In C, they are plain functions. The closest would be `FILE*` I/O C standard family functions, and they are just called [functions](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.21.6p1).

Answer (score 0):

I would use both "function" and "method".

"Function" would refer to the implementation, since it is actually a function, not a method.

"Method" would refer to how the function is used, since you want to emulate OOP, and you even call it as-if it would be a method. Of course, you will not be able to use advanced OOP features of the "method", but you accepted that when you decided to use C instead of C++.

Answer (score -1):

I would call them methods.

If Rust can call it [methods](https://doc.rust-lang.org/1.24.0/book/second-edition/ch05-03-method-syntax.html), sure you can.